# Error in fetching data from api in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-http

I have to fetch data from this api - https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/market-status
I am getting "xmlhttprequest error"

how should I overcome this.

```
Future<void> fetchUserData() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.https('api.wazirx.com', '/api/v2/market-status'));
  
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception("Request Rejected");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
add the headers 'Accept' : 'application/json'

```
Future<void> fetchUserData() async {
  final host = 'api.wazirx.com';
  final path = '/api/v2/market-status'; 
  final headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'};
  final uri = Uri.https(host, path);
  final response = await http.get(uri, headers: headers);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception("Request Rejected");
  }
}
```